# Maven artifact plugin buildinfo remove unwanted buildinfo information

Tags: java, maven, build, maven-plugin, artifact

On using

```
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-artifact-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.0</version>
    </plugin>
```

I am able to get buildinfo file generated as following as per https://reproducible-builds.org/docs/jvm/

```
#### Work In Progress ####
buildinfo.version=1.0-SNAPSHOT

name=name  
group-id=groupId  
artifact-id=artifact id   
version=version  

**source information**  
no scm configured in pom.xml  

**build instructions**  
build-tool=mvn

**effective build environment information**  
java.version=11
java.vendor=Oracle corporation
os.name=Linux

**Maven rebuild instructions and effective environment:**  
mvn.version=Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)


**output**  
outputs.0.filename=pom file name
outputs.0.length=<1234
outputs.0.checksums.sha512=abcd
```

**Apart from name,group-id,artifact-id and version, i don't want other properties to be generated in that file. how can i configure that using maven-artifact-plugin**

I have checked the doc https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-artifact-plugin/plugin-info.html, couldn't find example of removing unwanted information from getting generated in that file.

Comment: What is your actual goal? information about name, groupId, artifactId and version is already stored by `maven` in resulting jar - check `META-INF/maven/`. `reproducible build` guys have performed some research and got a conclusion about what information *must be* stored in artifact, if you do not store all information required - that is not `reproducible build`. Is your project based on spring-boot?

Comment: hey @AndreyB.Panfilov thanks for responding.  
using maven-artifact-plugin i want the only above mentioned 4 properties to be generated during this goal of build info and not other information which is being generated as this is a frontend repo in which maven is used for building the zip file and used for deployment and this buildinfo file needs to be shown in public folder so it can be viewed from browser which version of build app is being using currently,which is working fine,but there are too many details which is being generated , i feel it is unnecessary and want it to be removed

Answer (score 0):

You may achieve something similar using `maven-resources-plugin` and optionally `copy-rename-maven-plugin` (if you need to get particular name of buildinfo file)

contents of .buildinfo:

```
name=${project.name}
group-id=${project.groupId}
artifact-id=${project.artifactId}
version=${project.version}
```

maven configuration:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>build-info</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <includes>
                            <include>.buildinfo</include>
                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.coderplus.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>copy-rename-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-and-rename-file</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>rename</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <sourceFile>${project.build.directory}/.buildinfo</sourceFile>
                <destinationFile>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.buildinfo</destinationFile>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```